# Camera pose estimation using QR codes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, qr-code, camera-calibration, zbar

i'm trying to learn camera pose estimation and have been been through quite a lot of material. I want to calculate the pose of the camera using QR codes (quick response code) set up like this on an standard A4:

A0 A1

B0 B1

C0 C1

- Took some photos of the QR codes which i printed out on A4 paper, which have dimensions 210mm x 297 mm

This is a short code i wrote in MATLAB to get the coordinates of the world points where i assume the bottom left corner is (0,0)

```
n=2; %number of qr in x direction
m=3; %number of qr in y direction
x_FE=50; %distance from left edge to point1 in mm
y_FE=270; %distance from bottom to top qr code
sqr_dist=27.6; %distance between qr codes [mm]
sqr_size=47.4; %size of qr code height or width [mm]
QRnames=['A0'; 'A1';'B0'; 'B1';'C0'; 'C1'];

for i=1:n %number of squares in x directions
    x1(i)=x_FE+sqr_dist*(i-1);
    x2(i)=x_FE+sqr_size+sqr_dist*(i-1);
end

for j=1:m %number of squares in y directions
    y1(j)=y_FE-sqr_dist*(j-1);
    y2(j)=y_FE-sqr_size-sqr_dist*(j-1);
end

 n=1;
for k=1:3 %qr in y direction
    for j=1:2 %qr in x direction
        p1=[x1(j),y1(k)]
        p2=[x1(j),y2(k)]
        p3=[x2(j),y2(k)]
        p4=[x2(j),y1(k)]
        varname1=(['p' int2str(i)]);
        varname2=(['x' int2str(j)]);
        varname3=(['y' int2str(j)]);
        eval([QRnames(n) int2str(j-1) 'w=[p1 p2 p3 p4]' ';' ]);
        n=n+1;
    end
end
```

Ive also checked the coordinates by measuring with a ruler

Using a Python script called ZBar which is a QR code reader. i can extract the image coordinates from the QR codes which is embedded in the QR code itself (i think).

The coordinates get saved in a .txt file which is setup this way

QRcode name  x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4

Here are the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5f0Q.jpg

here are some of the results coordinates:

**image2**

A0  452 495 454 878 836 878 834 493

B0  455 1099    453 1479    836 1477    836 1099

B1  1056    1099    1056    1477    1442    1481    1442    1096

C0  449 1702    444 2091    831 2093    833 1700

C1  1056    1701    1056    2095    1447    2102    1445    1706

A1  1057    491 1057    878 1443    873 1445    485

**image3**

A1  1046    375 1051    737 1417    725 1412    364

B0  479 955 482 1316    848 1310    843 950

A0  475 389 477 747 841 740 835 379

B1  1053    946 1058    1307    1426    1302    1421    938

C1  1061    1518    1066    1895    1444    1895    1432    1517

C0  481 1528    479 1901    851 1896    848 1521

**image8**

A0  528 484 483 738 879 728 891 476

A1  1104    472 1109    728 1512    716 1473    463

B0  452 906 389 1240    852 1237    870 899

B1  1113    896 1119    1234    1595    1226    1540    884

C0  343 1472    248 1957    809 1953    839 1465

C1  1126    1463    1139    1952    1717    1955    1633    1461

**image9**

A0  2040    560 1741    553 1818    812 2138    811

B0  1562    548 1242    537 1282    806 1625    809

A1  2200    977 1866    980 1969    1311    2325    1301

C0  1047    528 691 515 689 797 1073    804

B1  1665    979 1308    984 1359    1328    1751    1318

C1  1090    983 685 985 677 1359    1119    1340

**image10**

A1  562 823 943 814 993 517 643 531

B1  1169    805 1571    793 1574    484 1201    504

A0  393 1409    835 1410    907 1010    506 1017

C1  1819    782 2268    768 2209    449 1801    471

B0  1098    1408    1571    1410    1570    997 1146    1003

C0  1862    1415    2390    1420    2309    982 1833    991

Here is information about the camera i used (ipod touch 5.gen):

```
         ExposureTime: 0.0167
                FNumber: 2.4000
        ExposureProgram: 'Normal program'
        ISOSpeedRatings: 32
            ExifVersion: [4x1 double]
       DateTimeOriginal: '2013:11:23 11:44:52'
      DateTimeDigitized: '2013:11:23 11:44:52'
ComponentsConfiguration: 'YCbCr'
      ShutterSpeedValue: 5.9069
          ApertureValue: 2.5261
        BrightnessValue: 5.9402
           MeteringMode: 'Pattern'
                  Flash: [1x148 char]
            FocalLength: 3.3000
            SubjectArea: [4x1 double]
              MakerNote: [196x1 double]
     SubsecTimeOriginal: '317'
    SubsecTimeDigitized: '317'
        FlashpixVersion: [4x1 double]
             ColorSpace: 'sRGB'
       CPixelXDimension: 1936
       CPixelYDimension: 2592
          SensingMethod: 'One-chip color area sensor'
              SceneType: 'A directly photographed image'
           ExposureMode: 'Auto exposure'
           WhiteBalance: 'Auto white balance'
       DigitalZoomRatio: 1.0021
  FocalLengthIn35mmFilm: 33
       SceneCaptureType: 'Standard'
            UnknownTags: [3x1 struct]
```

and info about the first test image

> > info=imfinfo('testimage1002.jpg')

info =

```
        Filename: 'D:\dropbox\Dropbox\campose\testimage_1\testimage1002.jpg'
     FileModDate: '23-Nov-2013 11:45:16'
        FileSize: 1188331
          Format: 'jpg'
   FormatVersion: ''
           Width: 1936
          Height: 2592
        BitDepth: 24
       ColorType: 'truecolor'
 FormatSignature: ''
 NumberOfSamples: 3
    CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
   CodingProcess: 'Sequential'
         Comment: {}
            Make: 'Apple'
           Model: 'iPod touch'
     Orientation: 1
     XResolution: 72
     YResolution: 72
  ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
        Software: '7.0.4'
        DateTime: '2013:11:23 11:45:16'
YCbCrPositioning: 'Centered'
   DigitalCamera: [1x1 struct]
         GPSInfo: [1x1 struct]
   ExifThumbnail: [1x1 struct]
```

i read the .txt files and set them up like this

```
txt=fopen('testimage1002.txt');
datascan01=textscan(txt,'%s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');

QRname01=[datascan01{1}];
x1=[datascan01{2}];
y1=[datascan01{3}];


% point 2
x2=[datascan01{4}];
y2=[datascan01{5}];


% point 3
x3=[datascan01{6}];
y3=[datascan01{7}];


% point 4
x4=[datascan01{8}];
y4=[datascan01{9}];

p1=0;p2=0;p3=0;p4=0;

for n=1:length(datascan01{1})
    for i=1:4
        for j=1:4
            varname1=(['p' int2str(i)]);
            varname2=(['x' int2str(i)]);
            varname3=(['y' int2str(i)]);
            varname4=([QRname01{n}]);
            eval(['p' int2str(i) '=[x' int2str(i) '(n)' ' y' int2str(i) '(n)];'])
            eval([varname4 '=[p1 p2 p3 p4]' ';' ]);
        end
    end
end
```

Now, i have image coordinates and world coordinates and want to find how the camera was standing when the image was captured.

ive looked at  Jean- Yves Bouget's Camera Calibration Toolbox but couldnt figure out how to use the functions using QR codes

also looked at 'Finding optimal rotation and translation between corresponding 3D points' (http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671)

But the resulting rotation matrix, translation vector and rmse seemed wrong. (got rmse=440?)

**Calibration matrix**

%Image Resolution: 2592 x 1936 pixels

ImgRes=[2592 1936];% pixels

Focallength= 3.3; % mm

%--- Calibration Results ---
% Focals (pixels) -

Fx= 2329.13;

Fy= 2324.04;

% Optical center -

Cx= 1307; Cy= 950.382;

%Radial distortion (Brown's Model)
K1= 0.236384;

K2= -0.680501;

K3= 0;

P1= 0.000319648;

P2= 0.000751849;

%pixel size fx=f/sx

sx=Focallength/Fx;

sy=Focallength/Fy;

distortion = [K1 K2 K3 P1 P2];

Any ideas on how i can do this (hopefully in matlab)? all help is appreciated

- Jonathan Brian

Answer (score 0):

The [Machine Vision Toolbox](http://www.petercorke.com/Machine_Vision_Toolbox.html) for Matlab, by Peter Corke, has the method `CentralCamera.estpose` described at page 38 of the [manual](http://www.petercorke.com/MVTB/vision.pdf).

The helps says:

> `CentralCamera.estpose`
>
> Estimate pose from object model and camera view
>
> `T = C.estpose(xyz, uv)` is an estimate of the pose of the object deﬁned
>   by coordinates `xyz` (3 x N) in its own coordinate frame. `uv` (2 x N) are the
>   corresponding image plane coordinates.
>
> Reference “EPnP: An accurate
>   O(n) solution to the PnP problem”, V. Lepetit, F. Moreno-Noguer, and
>   P. Fua, Int. Journal on Computer Vision, vol. 81, pp. 155-166, Feb.
>   2009.

and since you wrote

> Now, i have image coordinates and world coordinates and want to find
>   how the camera was standing when the image was captured.

it seems to me that you can use that function to estimate the pose.

Comment: Will this not give me an estimate of the pose of the QR codes?

Comment: i tried running it after calibrating and i get:
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  1.145272e-23. 
> In @CentralCamera\private\efficient_pnp at 79
  In CentralCamera.estpose at 32 
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  1.515760e-24. 
> In @CentralCamera\private\efficient_pnp at 107
  In CentralCamera.estpose at 32 

T =

   -1.0000    0.0026   -0.0007  175.2209
    0.0026    1.0000    0.0004 -197.8492
    0.0007    0.0004   -1.0000   -0.0966
         0         0         0    1.0000